# grails jms onMessage receives message text?? not Message

Tags: grails, groovy, jms

I have this in my listener service (following [doc](http://gpc.github.io/grails-jms/docs/manual/)):

```
@Queue(name='queue.web.dev')
def onMessage(Message msg) {
    println "DEBUG msgCorrelationID :"+msg.getJMSCorrelationID()
}
```

but on receiving message, I got error:

```
"No signature of method: java.lang.String.getJMSCorrelationID()"
```

If I try adding Message to onMessage args like:

```
def onMessage(Message msg)
```

I got error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: MessageListenerService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4bfa7a63.onMessage(java.lang.String)
```

Looks to me that onMessage is getting String message text. Is that true? How can I get whole jms.Message then?

Comment: How is the message being sent?

Comment: I directly entered the message from ActiveMQ admin console. Typed a random correlation id.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is still open  but you have to take the object out of the message yourself ..

```
def messageContents = ((ObjectMessage) message).getObject()
```

Is that what your looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the default message converter

```
jms {
    containers {
        standard {
            messageConverter = null
        }
    }
}
```

Check grails jms docs [here](http://gpc.github.io/jms/latest/guide/configuration.html#changingDefaults)